# Typescript auto imports are imported from @types folder

Tags: typescript

I have an issue using auto-imports with TypeScript and Webstorm.

The imports are imported from the `@types` folder instead of the library folder.

for example when I import `Request` from `express`, I get:

```
import { Request } from '@types/express';
```

instead of

```
import { Request } from 'express';
```

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2019"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/types/*"
      ]
    },
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "migrations/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/__tests-tape__/**",
    "src/**/__tests__/**"
  ]
}
```

Can I make typescript to resolve correctly the types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `"*": ["node_modules/*"]` from path mappings - this should solve the issue. Not sure why you need it, and how it is different from the TypeScript's default resolve for node_modules...